# Scroll down to contact form at bottom of page when form is submitted with errors

Tags: php, html, contact-form

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user tries to submit the form with errors and the error messages are added/page reloads I need the page to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the page to the contact form location.

I currently have the form within my `footer.php` and I'm including it in on each page like this: `<?php include('includes/footer.php') ?>`

here is my html for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
     <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

  <input name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

  <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone #" type="tel" />

  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>

  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

---

EDIT - 
Based on the answer below this is what fixed my problem...

```
<form method="post" action="#footer">
  //everything here
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While redirect to the page with error msg, add `#id_of_form_or_div` in your url.

Add id to your form or div which containing the form. If you add their id in url, then page will move to that particular section.

For example, You have id for footer as `footer`. Then you url will be 
`www.domain.com/index.php#footer`

Comment: This is what worked, I edited my question to reflect my solution. Thanks for answering - so obvious I should have known! o.O

Answer (score 2):

You can also print a javascript variable to know if there are errors, then with javascript scroll to the form.

something like:

```
var erros = "<?php echo $errors ?>";

<script>
    if (errors) {
        document.getElementById("form_id").scrollIntoView();
    }
</script>
```